# How load csv file to oracle table with procedure

Tags: oracle, csv, stored-procedures, plsql

I try load csv data to table from stored procedure

I have table with 3 columns: **id, name and values.**
In file i have this data:

```
id;name;values
1;aaa;32
2;bbb;23
3;cvv;12
4;fff;54
```

Next i write code to read from file test.csv

```
declare
 file utl_file.file_type;
 line varchar2(500);
begin
 file :=utl_file.fopen('DIRECTORY','test.csv','r');
loop
 utl_file.get_line(file ,line);
 dbms_output.put_line(line);
end loop;
exception
 when others then
utl_file.fclose(file );
end;
```

**It works good.** 
In next step **i needs insert all data from CSV to appropiate column of TABLE** excluded first line.

I try find resolve in internet, but i have still problem with this. Can you help me?

Comment: you can use sql loader

Comment: i know this, but i need use stored procedure

Comment: If you have to load manually for an assignment, you seem to be asking us to supply the solution, which isn't going to help you much. It would be better to show what you have attempted and what specific issues you have.

Comment: You should learn [sql loader](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_concepts.htm#g1013706) and [external table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/et_concepts.htm#g1017623) concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use external table instead of

Answer (score 2):

you will need to do some work on the `LINE` variable, use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` to split the line into its separate components, and then `INSERT` into your table with your new variables going into the correct columns.